inconsistency in upper and lower index dynamics in differential geometry
Consider relaxation of a vector field $\textbf{T}$ to the minimum of a free energy in a curvilinear coordinate with orthogonal basis and a metric $g_{ij}$.
The free energy is defined as
$F= \int dv f,$
where $f= \nabla_k T^m \nabla^k T_m$,
and upper and lower indices are usual differential geometry notation. Using the variational derivative of the free energy we can first find the dynamics of the upper index vector $T^a$ as
$\partial_t T^a  = - \frac{\delta F}{\delta T_a}= \nabla_k \nabla^k T^a. \:\:\:$    (Eq. 1)
We can then find the dynamics of the lower index vector field as
$\partial_t T_a = - \frac{\delta F}{\delta T^a}=\nabla_k \nabla^k T_a.$
Now, I try to use the dynamics of $T_a$ and convert it to something similar as the dynamics of $T^a$, using the metric. This reads
$\partial_t (g_{ab} T^b) =\nabla_k \nabla^k g_{ab} T^b=g_{ab} \nabla_k \nabla^k  T^b$.
Where in the last step I have used metric compatibility. This can be written as
$g_{ab} \partial_t T^b + T^b \partial_t g_{ab} =g_{ab} \nabla_k \nabla^k  T^b$,
which can be multiplied by $g^{ca}$ and then simplified to
$ \partial_t T^c = -T^b g^{ca} \partial_t g_{ab}+ \nabla_k \nabla^k T^c$
which is different from (Eq. 1) unless $T^b g^{ca} \partial_t g_{ab}=0$ . Could anyone help me understand what leads to this inconsistency? Which step is not correct? What is the difference between upper and lower indices?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
